# How can I rotate a section of a figure by 180 degrees?

Tags: pstricks, rotating

```
\documentclass[12pt,pstricks,border=15pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\def\myFig{%
\pscustom[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=yellow,opacity=.5]{%
\psarcn(3,0){3}{180}{90}\psarcn(1,3){2}{0}{-90}
\psarc(1,2){1}{-90}{0}\psarc(2,0){2}{90}{180}
}%
\pscustom[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=blue,opacity=.5]{%
\psarc(0,3){3}{-90}{0}\psarcn(1,3){2}{0}{-90}
\psarcn(2,1){1}{180}{90}\psarc(2,0){2}{90}{180}
\closepath
}%
}

\begin{pspicture}(6,6)
\rput(3,3){\myFig}
\rput{-90}(3,3){\myFig}
\rput{180}(3,3){\myFig}
\rput{-270}(3,3){\myFig}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

The above code produces this image:

[image: Existing Image]

How do I change it to produce this?

[image: Changed image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
\begin{pspicture}(6,6)
  \rput(3,3){\myFig}
  \rput{-180}(3,3){\psscalebox{-1 1}{\myFig}}% -1 1 -> reflecting 
  \rput{180}(3,3){\myFig}
  \rput(3,3){\psscalebox{-1 1}{\myFig}}
\end{pspicture}
```

[image]

Comment: Which package consist of \psscalebox?

Comment: basic command of `pstricks`

Comment: Wow, only be "basic" command. :-(

Comment: I found some bugs in PSTricks: [for the details](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/48202320#48202320)

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if this is the desired look. (yellow to the inside in quadrants II, IV)

```
\documentclass[12pt,pstricks,border=15pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\def\myFig{%
\pscustom[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=yellow,opacity=.5]{%
\psarcn(3,0){3}{180}{90}\psarcn(1,3){2}{0}{-90}
\psarc(1,2){1}{-90}{0}\psarc(2,0){2}{90}{180}
}%
\pscustom[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=blue,opacity=.5]{%
\psarc(0,3){3}{-90}{0}\psarcn(1,3){2}{0}{-90}
\psarcn(2,1){1}{180}{90}\psarc(2,0){2}{90}{180}
\closepath
}%
}

\begin{pspicture}(6,6)
\rput(3,3){\myFig}
\rput(6,0){\rotatebox{90}{\myFig}}
\rput{180}(3,3){\myFig}
\rput(0,6){\rotatebox{-90}{\myFig}}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: A lot of rotations and reflections are possible, but I think OP wants the figure to look like @herbert 's.

Comment: @AlexG You are obviously correct in your deduction.  I guess the implied (bent arrow) "rotation" is what threw me off, when it seems the OP wanted "reflection."